# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error when adding framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, error-handling, linker-errors

My project contains loads of different frameworks, but something happens every time I add the `Appodeal.framework`.

I get this strange `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error` error:

[image]

If I remove the `Appodeal.framework` the error goes away. Very frustrating.

I have tried deleting and re-adding it in different ways, but the same error appears every time. I've tried:

1. Dragging and dropping it to my project (made sure the copy items if needed was checked)
2. Right clicking my project and selecting "Add files to ..."
3. Build Phases > Link Binery With Libraries > + > Add Other...

Comment: PLease mention the steps you taken to add the framework!

Comment: 1. Dragging and dropping it to my project (made sure the copy items if needed was checked)
2. Right clicking my project and selecting "Add files to ..."
3. Build Phases > Link Binery With Libraries > + > Add Other...

Comment: What is the exact error message? Check by right clicking the error and selecting view in log.

Comment: @Nef10 I can't see no "View in log" when right clicking the error..?

Comment: Sorry, it is called `Reveal in Log`.

Comment: It's a whole lot of `duplicate symbol _kUnityAdsErrorDomain in:
    /Users/name/Pictures/project/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(UnityAds)
    /Users/name/Pictures/project/UnityAds.framework/UnityAds(UnityAds)`.

And below all of them it says: `2566 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64`

Comment: Appodeal framework may need a library to work, make sure to read their documentation.. match-linker only comes when you dont have a required file